# DLT error when reading pcap file created with Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, pcap, tcpreplay

I have created a pcap file using Scapy with some dummy values like

```
pkt = IP(dst="116.73.117.174", src="239.50.50.12") / UDP(sport=10812, dport=42)/ Raw(load=b"Data"))
pkt.show2() # Calculates checksum
wrpcap('DATA.pcap', pkt, append=True)
```

But when I read the same file using tcpreplay --intf1=eno1 --oneatatime DATA.pcap

I get

```
Warning in flows.c:flow_decode() line 259:
Unable to process unsupported DLT type: Raw IPv4 (0xe4)
```

How can I set the right DLT for the pcap which can be processed by tcpreplay ?

Comment: You didn't give your packet a datalink layer. `Ether() / IP(dst . . .` or `Dot11() / IP(dst . . .` should resolve that.

Comment: Yes that was indeed the answer. Adding a Ether(). Thanks !